# Windows Server 2008 for Development Environment

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have a spare machine that I want to install Windows Server 2008 for development purposes.  This would be in an isolated, development network.  I know SQL Server offers a Developer Edition (which is Enterprise Edition capabilities/features with just licensing restricted to development/demoing/etc.) for this type of thing, is there an equivalent offer for Windows Server OS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a valid .edu e-mail account, you can go to  [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx)  to get full copies of **Server '08** and **Server '08R2**.  Standard only, though.

Answer (score 2):

Both are included as part of MSDN

Answer (score 2):

No, but if you have a TechNet subscription, you are entitled to install whatever version of Windows Server you want for development or testing as long as it is not used in a production environment.

Comment: I have searched but I can't seem to find how to get a TechNet subscription?  Hopefully it isn't the financial burden of MSDN.

Comment: @Surfer513 it is a yearly subscription like MSDN, but neither are a burden. More like a drop in the bucket.

Comment: What's your definition of a drop in the bucket? :) please give me a rough estimate if you can.

Comment: Between $200 and $500. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/buy.aspx

Comment: Googling "buy tech net subscription" yielded this immediately, by the way. You might want to brush up on your google foo.